# onchange select radio isn't checked

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="1_1 value="1. Жетоны" "/>
<select id="1_1" onchange="document.GetElementById(this.id).checked=true;">
```

How come when I change option of `select`, `radio` isn't checked?

Thanks for carefuly!
But there is something else wrong, because it does not work too:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="1_1" value="1. Жетоны" "/>
<select name="1_1" onchange="document.GetElementById(this.name).checked=true;">
```

Thanks to shashi!

Comment: You still have an out-of-place double-quote at the end of your `input` tag. You're also still using the wrong character-case in your javascript - it must be `getElementById`, starting with a lower-case g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace,

`document.GetElementById(this.id)` with   `document.getElementById(this.id);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: Somehow I failed to notice that error when writing my own answer.

Comment: You're depending on a quirk that browsers may return the first element where duplicate IDs are used. They may return the last.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong:
- Your `input` tag is invalid HTML - it's missing a closing double-quote on the `id` attribute's value, and you have an out-of-place double-quote at the end of the tag.
- It looks like you're trying to use the same id for both the `input` and `select` tag. You can't do that; their ids must be different.

Comment: Thank you! But there is something else wrong, because it does not work too:

<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="1_1" value="1. Жетоны" "/>
<select name="1_1" onchange="document.GetElementById(this.name).checked=true;">

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs must be unique in a page, however element names can be repeated. Also, form controls must have a name to be successful (i.e. be submitted to the server).

So you can fix the problem by using references to form controls (and fixing the markup):

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="1_1" value="1.blah">
  <select name="whatever" id="1_1" onchange="this.form.radiobutton.checked=true;">
   <option>0
   <option>1
  </select>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Note that you need a reset button, otherwise it's impossible to uncheck the radio button without reloading the page (or the user running a script).